# Programming a peaking filter (and how do I FFT?)

Tags: fft, filters, audio

I want to get into audio signal processing. I know how to generate a tone, but I have no idea how filters work. What do I do to a set of samples to boost/cut a frequency with adjustable bandwidth? What is FFT? What's the code behind a parametric equalizer?

Comment: [**Indeed**](http://static2.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/Aw+hell+that+s+nasty+_adff56adebf5c35c030af0d3792ab045.jpg) @robertbristow-johnson ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to familiarize with concepts such us:

- FIR filters and their frequency response: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response
- Nyquist frequency and sample frequency:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem
- And then, have a look to the filters used for equalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalization_(audio)

Hope these basic links help you to do a bit more of research :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you may need also to get familiar with the FFT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Comment: have a look to this example in Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55885-dft-h--n-